# React Redux - store updates, component re-renders... but not with new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a complicated App with a problem which I have reduced down to 3 files below. Essentially, what is happening is:

- component loads and render initial text
- a spoof API is then triggered which calls `this.props.route.onLoadData()`
- this in turn calls a reducer which returns a new object containing updated text
- the component re-renders accordingly, but not with the updated text

I'm using `<Provider/>` and `connect()` - neither succeeds.

Any ideas?

---

**index.js**

---

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import Reducers from './reducers'
import Problem from './Problem'

var store = createStore(Reducers)

var routes = [
  { path: '/problem',
    component: Problem,
    data: store.getState(),
    onLoadData: (res) => store.dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA', data: res })
  }
]

var render = function() {
  return ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes}/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )
}

render()
store.subscribe(render)
```

---

**problem.js**

---

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

var ProblemContainer = React.createClass({

  spoofAPI() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ text: 'updated text' })
      }, 1000)
    })
  },

  componentDidMount() {

    this.spoofAPI().then((res) => {
      return this.props.route.onLoadData( res )
    }, console.error)

  },

  render() {

    var text = this.props.route.data.text

    console.log('render:', text)

    return (
      <div>{text}</div>
    )

  }

})

const mapState = state => ({ text: state })
export default connect(mapState)(ProblemContainer)
```

---

**reducers.js**

---

```
export default (state = { text: 'initial text' }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'LOAD_DATA':
      var newState = Object.assign({}, state)
      console.log('reducer - existing state: ', newState.text)
      newState.text = action.data.text
      console.log('reducer - receives: ', action.data.text)
      var returnObject = Object.assign({}, state, newState)
      console.log('reducer - returnObject: ', returnObject)
      return returnObject

    default:
      return state

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to these two pieces of code:

```
var routes = [
  ... 
  data: initialState,
  ...
]
```

and

```
render() {
  var text = this.props.route.data.text
  ...
}
```

It looks like what you are doing is always referencing one and the same piece of data (which is `initialState`) without even touching store.

**UPDATE.** What you have to do is to connect your `Component` to store via `react-redux` and use store values in your `Component`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
const Foo = React.createClass({
  ...
  render() {
    var text = this.props.text
    console.log('render:', text)
    return (
      <div>{text}</div>
    )
  }
})
const mapState = state => ({ text: state });
export default connect(mapState)(Foo);
```

Comment: would you replace it with:
var routes = [
  ... 
  data: store.getState(),
  ...
]

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've updated the question to reflect your suggestions. Unfortunately this still isn't updating.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `onGetState()` which can be called from the component works... but is this an anti-pattern of sorts (?)

**index.js**

```
var routes = [
  { ...
    onGetState: () => store.getState()
    ...
  }
]
```

**problem.js**

```
  render() {
    var { text } = this.props.route.onGetState()
    ...

  }
```

Comment: That doesn't looks right for me. First issue is that it is not idiomatic: when you use `react-redux` folks assume you'll pass state data to components via `mapStateToProps` argument of `connect` function. Second issue is that this way your are not using all the nice features `react-redux` provides you with, like avoiding re-rendering if `mapStateToProps` output didn't change.